# How to alter/create a table which has a column that defaults to a future date's datetimeoffset?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is what I am trying in my code:

```
ALTER TABLE xTable
Add xDate [datetimeoffset](7) 
NOT NULL 
DEFAULT (TODATETIMEOFFSET('2020-01-01 00:00:00.000', '+00:00'))
```

This runs down to a default value of `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000` rather than desired value `2020-01-01 00:00:00.000`, `+00:00`

Comment: May we ask how having this default would actually help you?  Wouldn't you still need to make a function call to add/subtract from this default value?

Comment: I need to add this column for a future implementation, for now I want this to be a default value. Basically I want to set this as trial period end date for all customers for my application.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, and also I'm not sure if there is a way to specify a literal date time offset, other than what you did with a function call, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query statement

```
ALTER TABLE xTable
Add xDate DateTimeOffset NOT NULL default '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 +00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/16/sql-server-datetime-function-todatetimeoffset-example/) to TODATETIMEOFFSET Explanation.

If you need to find the current offset of the system date then use 
[SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

TODATETIMEOFFSET will just store the offset value specified in the offset parameter.

Check the code here, it outputs the data specified in **DEFAULT** column

http://rextester.com/OHUE92372

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad, the query was correct, I forgot to configure my automapper for the entity which was resulting in overriding values.